# VB6 - Get accessor not working for array property

Tags: arrays, properties, vb6, accessor

I have two properties in my VB6 code:

```
Public Property Get PropFileID() As Long
    PropFileID = m_FileID
End Property

Public Property Get PropFileIDArray() As Long()
    PropFileIDArray = m_FileIDArray
End Property
```

While debugging, I can see the first property (PropFileID) being assigned a value without error. m_FileID has a value, and after passing through the Get accessor, PropFileID gets the same value.

While debugging the second property (PropFileIDArray), I can see that m_FileIDArray has a valid array value. However, after passing through the Get accessor, PropFileIDArray remains empty.

Am I making some kind of error in the syntax?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The class code looks ok. Maybe something is wrong in the consuming part? Here is an example that works for me:

'Class1

```
Private m_FileIDArray(2) As Long

Public Sub SetValues()
    m_FileIDArray(0) = 0
    m_FileIDArray(1) = 1
    m_FileIDArray(2) = 2
End Sub

Public Property Get PropFileIDArray() As Long()
    PropFileIDArray = m_FileIDArray
End Property
```

'Form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim class1 As class1

    Set class1 = New class1

    class1.SetValues

    Dim pa As Variant

    pa = class1.PropFileIDArray

    MsgBox pa(0)
    MsgBox pa(1)
    MsgBox pa(2)

    Set class1 = Nothing
End Sub
```